# Different behavior between clang++ and g++ (using c++17)

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I was trying to use some modern c++ dark magic, in order to test if a class has a member function called funcA.

And... it backfired...

It worked perfectly using "g++ -std=c++17  main.cpp".

But when I compiled the same code with "clang++ -std=c++17  main.cpp", it returned false even that the class had this function!

Can you suggest how to over come this problem? Assuming that I must use clang++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
template <typename, typename, typename = void>
struct HasFuncA : std::false_type {};
template <typename T, typename S>
struct HasFuncA<T, S, std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().template funcA(std::declval<S>()))>> : std::true_type {};

class MyClass
{
public:
    void funcA(int) const{}
};

int main(){
    std::cout<<HasFuncA<MyClass, int>()<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/templated-check-for-the-existence-of-a-class-member-function for how to achieve the goal

Comment: @M.M thanks for that. I see that this link talks about functions with no parameters.
I want to check if the class has funcA function with specific parameter as input.
Any idea on how to use the answer in the link for that?

Comment: Why `template funcA`? `funcA` is not a template. Without `template`, your code [produces expected outcome](https://godbolt.org/z/Eoxrj8)

Comment: Please add the c++ tag to C++ questions so that more users see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Igor Tandetnik  answer solved the problem.

I removed the word template from this line

```
struct HasFuncA<T, S, std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().template funcA(std::declval<S>()))>> : std::true_type {};
==>
struct HasFuncA<T, S, std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>(). funcA(std::declval<S>()))>> : std::true_type {};
```

and it worked!

Still have no idea what exactly happened.. but this is working now!

Thanks Igor!